Analytically Solving an Equation System of the type $kn x^{n - 1} + x^n$ for $k$ and $n$
So i am confronted during my research for my thesis right now with the following issue - I am trying to solve the following system of equations for k and n.
\begin{equation}
k \cdot n \cdot x^{(n-1)}\cdot y = u
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
k \cdot (n \cdot x^{(n-1)}\cdot z+\frac{x^n}{r}) = v
\end{equation}
I am aware at this point that i can solve this nummerically with some method but i would like to go on about this as simply as possible and solve it analytically
My efforts and solutions so far are as follows:

I have read about the Lamberts Function and its ability to solve such equations where the unknown is given in the form as in my equations
\begin{equation}
x \cdot e^x = y \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad x = W(y)
\end{equation}
I have managed to extract the unknown n from both equations
\begin{equation}
k \cdot n \cdot x^{(n-1)}\cdot y = u \Leftrightarrow n = \frac{1}{\ln(x)} \cdot W\left(\frac{1}{k}\cdot\frac{\ln(x) \cdot x \cdot u}{y}\right)
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
k \cdot (n \cdot x^{(n-1)}\cdot z+\frac{x^n}{r}) = v \Leftrightarrow n = \frac{1}{\ln(x)} \cdot W\left(\frac{1}{k}\cdot\frac{x}{ z} \cdot \ln(x) \cdot v \cdot x^{\frac{x}{ z \cdot r} \cdot \ln(x)}\right) - \frac{x}{ z \cdot r}
\end{equation}

I have tried to solve this equation system but setting $n=n$ but upon further inspection i believe this is close to impossible given the Lambert Function on both sides...
\begin{equation}
n = \frac{1}{\ln(x)} \cdot W\left(\frac{1}{k}\cdot\frac{\ln(x) \cdot x \cdot u}{y}\right)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
n = \frac{1}{\ln(x)} \cdot W\left(\frac{1}{k}\cdot\frac{x}{ z} \cdot \ln(x) \cdot v \cdot x^{\frac{x}{ z \cdot r} \cdot \ln(x)}\right) - \frac{x}{ z \cdot r}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\Leftrightarrow
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{\ln(x)} \cdot W\left(\frac{1}{k}\cdot\frac{\ln(x) \cdot x \cdot u}{y}\right) = \frac{1}{\ln(x)} \cdot W\left(\frac{1}{k}\cdot\frac{x}{ z} \cdot \ln(x) \cdot v \cdot x^{\frac{x}{ z \cdot r} \cdot \ln(x)}\right) - \frac{x}{ z \cdot r}
\end{equation}
And by grouping known parameters under single variables to simplify the equation we can write
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{y} \cdot W\left(\frac{b}{k}\right) = \frac{1}{y} \cdot W\left(\frac{p}{k}\right)-m
\end{equation}
Do you think this equation is solvable for k? And if yes, how would you go about it having the W Function inside it
My next idea would probably be to substitute an expression for $n=W(...)$ in the initial equation system and try to solve for k given only one Lamberts expression. Something like this:
\begin{equation}
n = \frac{1}{\ln(x)} \cdot W\left(\frac{1}{k}\cdot\frac{x}{ z} \cdot \ln(x) \cdot v \cdot x^{\frac{x}{ z \cdot r} \cdot \ln(x)}\right) - \frac{x}{ z \cdot r} \rightarrow k \cdot n \cdot x^{(n-1)}\cdot y = u \rightarrow k = ...
\end{equation}

I have been working on this for some weeks now and I have stayed so far positive and hopeful there is an analytical solution to my problem. I hope that by approaching this issue also on this forum, I can find some guidance from someone with more experience or at least a different perspective on my task at hand
All comments are much appreciated! I wish you a nice day and thank you for taking your time for reading:)
P.S. All numbers should be real, n should belong to [0,1]

What you wrote in the title is not an equation. Are you missing an $=0$ or $=c?$

At first glance , this is not easier than simply solving the system numerically , but this impression might be wrong. Maybe someone else can help better.

If you eliminate $k$ using $k=\frac v{n x^{n-1}z+\frac{x^n}r}$, you get $u=\frac{n r v y}{nrz+x}\implies n=\frac{ux}{(vy-uz)r}$ which can be substituted in. Is there anything wrong with doing this? Also, your title says “ $kn x^{n - 1} + x^n$”, but your question does not

Yes, i apologize, the title is sligthly misleading, the equations to solve are as listed in the thread in the beginning. The reason of the title i chose is to show at first glance the form of the equation..but not the equation it self

Maple 13's solve command yields:
$$k=-\frac{r}{y}(uz-vy)x^\frac{ux}{r(uz-vy)},\ \ n=-\frac{ux}{r(uz-vy)}.$$
Maple 13's eliminate command yields:
$$n=\frac{1}{\ln(x)}W\left(\frac{ux\ln(x)}{ky}\right),\ \ k=-\frac{r}{y}(uz-vy)x^\frac{ux}{r(uz-vy)},$$
or
$$k=\frac{u}{ny}x^{1-n},\ \ n=-\frac{ux}{r(uz-vy)}.$$
See also Wolfram Alpha's answer.
You could also try SageMathCell.
